# Size of variables char into a structure (C ANSI)

Tags: c, char, structure

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Wdd
    {
        char protocolId[4];
        char messageId[4];
        char sizeBody[4];
    };

main()
{

    struct Wdd msgWdd;

    strcpy(msgWdd.protocolId, "GABC");
    strcpy(msgWdd.messageId, "WDSS");
    strcpy(msgWdd.sizeBody, "0020");

    printf("protocolId: %s\n", msgWdd.protocolId);
    printf("messageId: %s\n", msgWdd.messageId);
    printf("sizeBody: %s\n", msgWdd.sizeBody);
    printf("sizeStructure: %d\n", sizeof(msgWdd));
}
```

The result of the print is

```
protocolId: GABCWDSS0020
messageId: WDSS0020
sizeBody: 0020
sizeStructure: 12
```

WHY? If I change the size of the fields for '5', the print is (correct, like I expected)

```
protocolId: GABC
messageId: WDSS
sizeBody: 0020
sizeStructure: 15
```

Why?

I've read the compiler pad some bytes to alignment requirements, but I couldn't really understand it. To fix this should I just increase the size of the fields (to 5) or is there another way around?

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null characters need a fifth byte. Otherwise, the null character is written at the same offset where the next field starts, and copying a string to the next field effectively overwrites the last null character. Printing out the strings simply involves looping over each character, until `\0` is found.

The `char` type has the least strict alignment requirements, that is, it can be located at any address, so the compiler doesn't insert any padding.

Comment: Note that compiler is free to add "holes" between struct members and also after last member as well. In other words `offsetof(struct Wdd, messageId)` does not necessarily is equal to `4`.